# Jasny Bootstrap off canvas nav on mobile screens with sticky footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer, jasny-bootstrap

I'm using a sticky footer on my responsive site, as well as the Jasny Bootstrap off canvas nav plugin (which is great, btw). However, I've noticed that on pages where there is not much content, when on a mobile device (sm and xs size), the sticky footer jumps up to the bottom of the content when the off canvas nav is opening up. Has anyone else experienced this, or know of a solution? I'm only using the off canvas nav for sm screen sizes and smaller, so this is not a problem on the desktop version of the site. The footer doesn't stay 'sticky' in these situations and jumps up to the bottom of the content, leaving a gap underneath.

[Link to a screen shot of what I'm talking about](http://screencast.com/t/kE9XIwTi) (can't upload an image yet)

Comment: Need to post your code on JSFiddle or somewhere we can take a look.

Comment: is it zooming out as well?

Comment: @tmg no, it doesn't seem to zoom out, footer just jumps 'up' to wherever the bottom of the content on the page is.

Answer (score 0):

Change line: 240 in Jasny-bootstrap.js

From: 
 if ($(this).css('position') === 'static') $(this).css('position', 'relative')

To:
if ($(this).css('position') === 'static') $(this).css('position', 'absolute')